# Handling user sessions and active statuses

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, authentication

Normally I would handle a logged in user by setting a session after a successful login. That session is then checked on each request to ensure it exists.

But was about if I disabled a user account and they were currently logged in? In that case, the user would still have access to the system until their session expired.

Currently, I am pulling the account information from the database on every request and checking the status field. I feel this is a lot of unnecessary overhead. In my scenario, there are accounts and users within those accounts. Therefore, I'm having to check the account status as well as the user status on each request.

Is there a better way? Note that I'm using SQL Server Session State as this a multi-server environment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the session ID's in the database on session start. When you disable a user just remove the value in the user session id field in your database.

Check if the session id matches the stored session id in your database on requests.

If not, session.abandon().

Answer (score 0):

When you disable a user account, why not remove any sessions associated with the account.  Then we user accesses the server, the session will no longer exist and user will not have access.

Comment: When I look at the sessions table, the only useful info I see is a SessionId column. How do I know which session id goes to which users? Would I need to retrieve the created session id (if so, how?) and save it to the database in a "CurrentSessionID" field? or is there an easier way to associate the session record with the user?

Answer (score 0):

> You can use cookies ! Cookies are most powerful light weight data
>   storage ! store encrypted username information & state(active/deactive)
>   into cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the data on each request, after the first request, you can implement a method like `AuthenticationManager.IsAuthorized("user name")`. This method should return two values:

- True/False (If it's authorized or not, respectively).
- Reason as an enumeration: UserBlocked, Timeout, ...

Thus, you'll be checking if the session is still valid on every request and the user data will be retrieved once per session start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Anonymous Identification if enabled with in your Application:

```
<anonymousIdentification enabled="true"/>
```

and you can get it like:

```
string strId = Request.AnonymousID;
```

where default it's Guid.

AnonymousId is unique for each **user** and you will keep track of your users as they IsAuthenticated or not.